# Plotly : Assign pandas series to customdata attribute of scattermapbox

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I am using plotly scattermapbox and am in process of making code improvements. To the `customdata` property of scattermapbox, I'd like to assign multiple pandas series. In the callback, I read this data and populate a modal pop-up based on click event. Here's the code:

```
layout = html.Div([

                # Plot properties map
                dcc.Graph(id="map-graph"),

                html.Div([

                dbc.Modal(
                    [
                        dbc.ModalHeader("Info"),
                        dbc.ModalBody(
                            [

                                
                                dbc.Label("Name:"),
                                dbc.Label("Id"),
                                
                            ]
                        ),
                        dbc.ModalFooter(
                            [
                                dbc.Button("OK"),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
                    id="modal-1",
                ),

            ], style={"width": "50%"}),

)]
```

Callback to append data and define layout for `map-graph`, only posting relevant code snippet:

```
          result_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4],  
                                    'name':['a','b','c','d'], 
                                    'val': [5,6,7,8], 
                                    'lat':[.....], 
                                    'long':[....]
                      })  

           data = []

           lat = result_df["lat"]
           lng = result_df["long"]
           
           data.append({

                        "type": "scattermapbox",
                        "lat": lat,
                        "lon": lng,
                        "mode": "markers",
                        "clickmode": "event+select",
                        "customdata": { "Name": result_df["name"],
                                        "id": result_df["id"]},
                        "marker": {
                                   "symbol": "circle",
                                   "size": 12,
                                   "opacity": 0.7,
                                   "color": "black"
                                  }
                        }
           )
```

Callback that reads `customdata`, parses as `json` data and then populate the `modal` based on selection.

```
@application.callback(
                          [
                               Output("modal-1","is_open"),

                               
                               Output("name","children"),
                               Output("val","children"),
                                                        ],
                          [
                               # Button clicks

                               Input("map-graph1","clickData"),
                               Input("c-button", "n_clicks"),
                               Input("close","n_clicks1")
                          ],

                          [
                                State("modal-1", "is_open")
                          ],
                    )
def display_popup(clickData, n_clicks, close, is_open):

    if clickData:

        res = json.dumps(clickData, indent=2)

        Name = clickData["points"][0]["customdata"]["Name"]
        id = clickData["points"][0]["customdata"]["id"]
        

        return(not is_open, Name, id,)

    elif close:

        return is_open

    else:

        return (no_update)
```

Here's what the response from clickData looks like when I print:

```
{
  "points": [
    {
      "curveNumber": 0,
      "pointNumber": 15,
      "pointIndex": 15,
      "lon": -118.27600459999998,
      "lat": 34.0456796,
    }
  ]
}
```

`customdata` is missing from the response. How do I tie tie the data back to `(lat, long)` clicked on the `map-graph` and populate the modal with `Name`, `id` etc information from custom data.

Answer (score 0):

- have used UK hospitals as sample data to scatter
- it's simpler to use **Plotly Express** to generate the mapbox figure
- `hover_data` uses `customdata` to store data for hover.  Updated template so data is held within trace but not displayed on hover
- your modal did not have anywhere to put the **ID** and **Name**, created two additional `Div` for this.  Have not beautified
- the **callback** is much simpler than you coded it.  Only input is **clickData**, outputs are pretty obvious.  Navigated `clickData` **dict** to get *ID* and *Name*

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import requests, io, json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that has GPS lat / lon
dfhos = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),sep="¬",engine="python",)

# columns to be used as custom data, i.e. hoverdata
cd = ["OrganisationCode", "Sector", "OrganisationName", "Postcode"]

# update hovertemplate so it does not display all the columns added as customdata
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    dfhos.sample(30),
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    hover_name="OrganisationName",
    hover_data=cd,
).update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<b>%{hovertext}</b><br><br>Latitude=%{lat}<br>Longitude=%{lon}<br><extra></extra>",
)

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 4},
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    clickmode="event+select"
)

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        # Plot properties map
        dash.dcc.Graph(id="map-graph", figure=fig),
        dash.html.Div(
            [
                dbc.Modal(
                    [
                        dbc.ModalHeader("Info"),
                        dbc.ModalBody(
                            [
                                dbc.Label("Name:"),
                                dash.html.Div(id="modal-name"),
                                dbc.Label("Id"),
                                dash.html.Div(id="modal-id"),
                            ]
                        ),
                        dbc.ModalFooter(
                            [
                                dbc.Button("OK"),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ],
                    id="modal-1",
                ),
            ],
            style={"width": "50%"},
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [
        Output("modal-1", "is_open"),
        Output("modal-id", "children"),
        Output("modal-name", "children"),
    ],
    Input("map-graph", "clickData"),
)
def display_popup(clickData):
    if clickData:
        return (
            True,
            clickData["points"][0]["customdata"][cd.index("OrganisationCode")],
            clickData["points"][0]["customdata"][cd.index("OrganisationName")],
        )
    else:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

#### create figure with graph objects

```
df = dfhos.sample(30)
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df["Latitude"],
        lon=df["Longitude"],
        hovertext=df["OrganisationName"],
        customdata=df.loc[:, cd],
        hovertemplate="<b>%{hovertext}</b><br><br>Latitude=%{lat}<br>Longitude=%{lon}<br><extra></extra>",
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 4, "center": {"lat": df["Latitude"].mean(), "lon": df["Longitude"].mean()}},
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
    clickmode="event+select",
)
```

Comment: thanks. `plotly.express` does simplify it. However, I'd like to do be able to do this in plotly scattermapbox. It works for me when iterating over a pandas dataframe to construct customdata, but that's not efficient as iterating over a df is not recommended.

Comment: ok - have supplemented answer with building figure using graph objects instead of Plotly Express

Comment: so i tried your proposed solution, which is passing pandas columns to `customdata` and am still running into some issues. Here's the error: `InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `[<Output `map-graph.figure`>]`
            returned a value having type `tuple`
            which is not JSON serializable. `

The return statement goes like this: `return ({"data": data, "layout": layout})`

Comment: This line here is causing the problem: `customdata=df.loc[:, cd],`. When I remove it, the map renders fine before I get to clickData to populate the modal.

Comment: I upgraded the packages to be consistent with yours. I am still seeing `TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable`. I think `customdata` attribute doesn't like me passing a DataFrame object. More details in the chat room, if you don't mind checking.